# How to use placeholder inside sql replace() in java?

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I want to use placeholder inside sql replace function in java.
Following is the code.

```
import java.sql.*;


public class TestDB {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("class");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("url","username","password");
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        String query = "select name from image where id >= replace(?,'','','''') and id <= replace(?,'','','''') and  name like ''%aa'' order by id;"; 
        ps= con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, "1");
        ps.setString(2, "10");
        ResultSet rs = null;
        rs= ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }

    }
}
```

In `ps= con.prepareStatement(query);` line I am getting:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: An illegal character has been found in the statement.

Actually using a simple create statement it works fine. But when I use preparedstatement with placeholder it's throwing exception. 
Can anyone let me know what the issue is?

Comment: What is `name like ''%aa''` supposed to mean?

Comment: It means names ending with "aa".

Comment: I mean, why quotes are doubled?

Comment: Please tag your DBMS. MySQL? Oracle? Postgres?